# How to split a string using a char array separator in java?

Tags: java, split

like c#:

```
string[] Split(char[] separator, StringSplitOptions options)
```

is there an equivalent method in java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    char[] arrOperators = { ',', '^', '*', '/', '+', '-', '&', '=', '<', '>', '=', '%', '(', ')', '{', '}', ';' };
    String input = "foo^bar{hello}world"; // Expecting this to be split on the "special" chars
    String regex = "(" + new String(arrOperators).replaceAll("(.)", "\\\\$1|").replaceAll("\\|$", ")"); // escape every char with \ and turn into "OR"
    System.out.println(regex); // For interest only
    String[] parts = input.split(regex);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
}
```

Output (including the final regex for information/interest only):

```
(\,|\^|\*|\/|\+|\-|\&|\=|\<|\>|\=|\%|\(|\)|\{|\}|\;)
[foo, bar, hello, world]
```

Comment: Great. It works. Thanks. This can be accepted as the standard answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] split(String)
```

You can turn a `char[]` into a String with `String(char[]).`

Comment: char[] arrOperators = { ',', '^', '*', '/', '+', '-', '&', '=', '<', '>', '=', '%', '(', ')', '{', '}', ';' };

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for. The split method I supplied accepts regular expressions (regex). [Here's](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) a good tutorial on regex.

Comment: Illegal repetition near index 14

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `public String[] split(String regex)` and `java.util.regex`.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you want this. I'm not sure:

```
    String text = "abcdefg";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text.split("d|f|b")));
```

Results in:

```
   [a, c, e, g]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Regex, to achieve this. It will tell this on which basis you have to separate.
Like there is OR "|" operator. If you use

```
String regex = "a|b|c";
String[] tokens = str.split(regex)
```

It will split on a,b & c basis.

Comment: And how are you using regex ??? Read up regex yourself first before misleading others . What you have above is a string vairble called regex you could call it dog or cat as well

Comment: @Shahzeb, `String.split(String)` interprets its argument as a regex.

Comment: I want to split a String using

Comment: I want to split a String using: char[] arrOperators = { ',', '^', '*', '/', '+', '-', '&', '=', '<', '>', '=', '%', '(', ')', '{', '}', ';' };

Answer (score 0):

Another level up in functionality is Guava's [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html):

```
Splitter splitOnStuff = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("|,&"))
                                .omitEmptyStrings();

Iterable<String> values = splitOnStuff.split("value1&value2|value3,value4");
```

Answer (score 0):

Goold ol' StringTokenizer will do it too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String delim = ",^*/+-&=<>=%(){};";
    String str = "foo^bar{hello}world";
    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(str, delim);
    while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(tok.nextToken());
    }
}
```